# Кстати, о празднике

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос в тему праздника. Как вернее сказать: "с праздником Восьмого марта" или "с праздником Восьмое марта"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстаи да. С праздником, дорогие форумчанки!

Я думаю, что всё-таки просто " с Восьмым марта!" или "С праздником! :)
Ну или "с Международным женским днем".

А если уж очень хочется, то с "праздником восьмого марта". Тогда "восьмое марта" - не название, а просто дата.